# How to use my github repository as dependency in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

The problem is, I previously used a github repository (https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen) as my dependency:

```
compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.4.0'
```

It worked fine but now i have forked the repository, made some changes and I'm trying to use my repository as dependency, my repository: https://github.com/prasenjeetpaul/QRGen, I'm trying as:

```
compile 'com.github.prasenjeetpaul.QRGen:android:2.4.0'
```

I have sync the project many times but couldn't use my repository code, even after removing the old dependency it is still using the old code but not the new code from my github repository.

Is there a way to remove the old dependency code and use my new repository code??

Please help!

Comment: It doesn't work like that mate. Read more [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info @Vucko . I didn't knew this back-end process for creating a dependency. Your comment helped me a lot !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading your files to GitHub will **not** make your code to be available to be included as a dependency. First, make sure that your project is a library, and follow [these](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) steps to upload your library to Bintray's `jcenter()` repository so that your library can be included as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [bintray](https://bintray.com/) to upload my libs to jcenter repository but the process a little bit complicated so you may use [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) to publish new dependency immediately

Just add jitpack repo link to root build.gradle and it will work

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
  ...
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // add this line
 }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help
I get -- Failed to resolve: github.com.name:respo:version...